# youtubePlayer.loadVideo not working after activity resumes

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, youtube

My app uses youtubeFragment to play youtube videos. It also provides deep links  to play youtube videos inside my app.

For example deep link like www.abc.com/id/y/12345 opens my app and plays youtube video with id 12345 in my app.

Consider the scenario, 
When app is opened and user clicks on an element, youtube video is played. Now, if user presses home button while a youtube video is being played (app goes to background, video in youtube fragment pauses) and clicks on a deep link (say www.abc.com/id/y/56789), the app must open, youtube player must resume and play video with id 56789.

But here's the problem: youtube fragment when on pause, saves the state and loads the saved state when app is resumed. So when I call `youtubePlayer.loadVideo("56789")` the video with 56789 is not played as loading saved state is overriding my loadVideo call.

How do I overcome this without using a delayed handler or an asynctask ?